# why my php script is killed on debian

Tags: php, process, debian, vps

I run a big php script on debian

```
php myscript.php
```

After 5 minutes I have this message : "Killed"

I have a Virtual Private Server on (debian 512MB of RAM and 1Ghz CPU)

with this command :  `cat /proc/meminfo`

I get this :

```
MemTotal:         524288 kB
MemFree:          447928 kB
Cached:            12128 kB
Active:            48760 kB
Inactive:          12760 kB
Active(anon):      45332 kB
Inactive(anon):     4060 kB
Active(file):       3428 kB
Inactive(file):     8700 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:        131072 kB
SwapFree:          60012 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         49392 kB
Shmem:             20552 kB
Slab:              14820 kB
SReclaimable:       5616 kB
SUnreclaim:         9204 kB
```

I tried to reduce the memory_limit in php.ini into 32MB but it didn't succeed

When I try to execute the same script in WAMP on my local machine there is no error.

Someone can help ?

Comment: You have provided a negative quantity of information

Comment: A negative quantity?  Did he actually take information from you with his post?

Comment: @user1477388 Yes! I came here _more_ informed than I am now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server has a task monitor that kills long-running processes as a safeguard against lockups.

If you own the server, you should be able to disable it. If a host owns it, you can ask them for help. Usually the task monitor only applies to web requests, so Cron tasks for example are allowed to run as long as needed.

Comment: I'm the owner. How can you disable it ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wouldn't know.

Comment: You will need to learn how to become a system administrator and use the tools on your system! :D Time to ask http://superuser.stackexchange.com